# Using static Boost libraries with vcpkg and CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, vcpkg

I'm using the package manager `vcpkg` to install the (static) `Boost` libraries via `vcpkg install boost:x64-windows-static`.

Furthermore, I use `CMake` as my build system and I'm passing `C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake` to `CMake` via the `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` `CMake` command.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I force static `Boost` libraries:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem iostreams REQUIRED)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif ()

# ...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

However, `Visual Studio` still tries to look at the wrong file path for my `Boost` libraries:

```
Error 'C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib', needed by 'MyProject.exe', missing and no known rule to make it
```

If I install the dynamic `Boost` libraries, it will build fine since this is where `Visual Studio` looks. However, I want to use the static libraries in my build instead so that all `DLL`s are "merged" into the final `EXE`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If the path `C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib` is wrong, what is the **correct path** to the static library on your machine? According to the Boost library naming convensions, `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib` is actually a static library file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: The correct path would be `C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/lib/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib`. This is how `vcpkg` sets it up when I install the static libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

Solved with

```
define  set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "path")
```

before find_package force.

When you using `cmake` with `vcpkg`, find `_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR` variable in `CmakeCache.txt`

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/x64-windows-static/include)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that by default vcpkg.cmake script auto-detect dynamic libraries that are installed by vcpkg.

You can override this behavior for your project by setting a variable when invoking cmake:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=.../vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static
```

Or using the CMakePresets.json:

```
"cacheVariables": {
 ...
  "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": {
    "value": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
    "type": "FILEPATH"
  },
  "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET": "x64-windows-static"
},
```

I haven't yet found how to do this on a per library basis.

More details [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/) and [here](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-commands.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I have found to work correctly is the following CMake:

```
# Boost settings
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)  # only find static libs
set(Boost_USE_DEBUG_LIBS        OFF)  # ignore debug libs and
set(Boost_USE_RELEASE_LIBS       ON)  # only find release libs
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME     ON)  # link Boost Static libraries
```